# Read txt file in (html) page

Tags: html

First I don't know almost anything about HTML.
I have .txt file that looks like this

4WWWWWWWWWWWWW_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**_11111

1imeq_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**_22222

2i_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**_33333

3Leteca pegla_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***_44444

4name_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**_55555

1name_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**_66666

2name_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**_77777

3name_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**_88888

4name_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**_99999

1name_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**_00000

and I want to edit this page http://elektro-srb.webs.com/high-score so that it shows content of this file. File will update from time to time.
"_" is actually space in file but because of some strange formatting here I changed it.
I need as simple solution as it can be.

Comment: you can't do it using html only.

Comment: Ok but what is next simplest solution than?

Comment: either load file dynamically using JS ajax, parse it and inject into your website, or process the file on backend side (php?) and return parsed result as part of your html.

Comment: Ok but I don't know almost anything about web programming :/
i need simple solution as sample code

Comment: depends, where is the text file coming from, how is it being generated in the first place? you might be better off avoiding using it as a text file and just posting the data to the web server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299471/php-parsing-a-txt-file

Comment: I upload it with c program using curl as .txt file and its being uploaded to some other host site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with HTML. HTML is a markup language, you can't include a dynamic text in it.

You can use iframe and load the .txt file as a source, but note that this is not a vaild HTML format.

```
<iframe src="your_file.txt" />
```

If you're using s server side language you can load the .txt content. For example in php:

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents("your_file.txt");
?>
```

Comment: Ok but what is next simplest solution than?

Comment: and how to show info from that file on page?

Comment: Both solution shows the file's content in your HTML page.

Comment: thanks! webs.com dont allow me to add custom code so I cant do it there but works on other site.