# make tr visible depending on username all other unvisible

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a table containing messages that are clickable links with the following structure:

```
<tr><td>#</td><td><a href='messages/". $file .".php'>$file</a></</td></tr>
...
```

`$file` always has this kind of structure as document name:

```
Date of submission [2014-02-19] - Subject [clean the garage] - To(everybody)
```

the table looks like this:

```
Date of submission [2014-02-19] - Subject [clean the garage] - To(Everybody)
Date of submission [2014-02-15] - Subject [clean the bathroom] - To(Annita)
Date of submission [2014-02-11] - Subject [clean the livingroom] - To(Rudy)
```

when a user logs in the $username echo's out for example Annita or Rudy or... Now what i would like to know if it is possible to make only the `<tr>` 's visible for the logged in user with according `to(...)` name

for example when Annita is logged in, she only gets to see the `<tr>`'s that has her name in it, and that for example the `$file` `<tr>` with Rudy becomes invisible. When the message is `to(Everybody)` all users can see the message

I hope my question is clear and somebody can help or explain me... thx in advance. breaking my head over this, and i cant change the structure of the message names...

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to hide the content server side using PHP, i.e., only serve up the TRs that a user is supposed to see?

Comment: yes indeed, but the messages are from an external program saved in a specific directory, and i cant adjust that program, the only thing i can do is read out the directory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use PHP to parse the file for `$username`? If `$username` exists in the file, then you include it.

See here: [PHP - parsing a txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299471/php-parsing-a-txt-file)

E.g., I'm logged in as Rudy, so `$username = 'Rudy.'` Now I use PHP to find all the files that match the regular expression `/To\(Rudy\)$/` (which you'll write dynamically based on `$username`) and include them. Javascript is definitely not the right tool for the job here.